# ObjectiveCでセクションインデックスの並び順を変更したい

Tags: ios, objective-c

ObjectiveCでセクションインデックスを表示させたいのですが、
以下でセクションタイトルを見ると、A、B、C・・・あ、か、さ・・・#がNSLogで表示されました。
セクションインデックスはデフォルトでアルファベット、ひらがな、記号、のように設定されているものなのでしょうか？
iPhoneの電話帳を見るとひらがな、アルファベット、記号となっているのですが、電話帳と同じような設定変更はオプションなどで可能なのでしょうか？

```
NSInteger sectionNum = [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] count];
for(int i = 0; i < sectionNum; i++)
{
    NSString* title = [[collation sectionTitles] objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@",title);
}
```